# Settling Time and ADC Accuracy

Tags: adc

I'm working on understand ADC specifications a little bit better and I'm stuck on the topic of settling time.

I'm reading an [App Note from Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa036/slaa036.pdf) which talks about the settling time of the switched capacitor in the input of a ADC.

However for some reason I cannot quite understand, they talk about settling to within 1/16th of an  LSB in the acquisition time to get some required accuracy figure.

> The required input time constant must be small enough to be within the given
> ADC analog input sampling time (Ts) for the desired accuracy. In the case given
> in Section 4, 1/16 LSB was chosen to give an error of not more than 6.25%.

This is the bit I'm having trouble with:

- How does 1/16 LSB get you to 6.25% error.
- Surely as long as the input caps settle to within 1 LSB then you can't get more accurate than that?

Comment: 6.25% of one LSB, not of full scale.

Comment: sure you can have the outcome settle to more accuracy within 1LSB. Anywhere from 0 to 1LSB is 'within' 1LSB. Guaranteeing less settling within less than an LSB allows budgeting for other errors (such as DNL/INL) besides settling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 2.1 of the linked document explains their rationale for using 1/16th LSB as the target time for settling.

The author set the total conversion error target as +/- 1/2LSB including other errors such as DNL and INL. The allowable error budget for settling is assumed to be 0.1LSB that they have rounded down to 1/16th for the rest of the calculations.

Comment: This is exactly what I missed, I hadn't realised they were also budgeting for the other error sources in the ADC. Thanks!